# ReactS Azure AD Authentication issue with redirect url appnding null

Tags: reactjs, react-router, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to integrate Azure AD Authentication using react-adal library.
But after successful authentication it is getting redirected to base-url/null and getting error requested resource does not exsist. This issue is only happening in the application deployed in appservice. And the redirection is working fine when running in localhost

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console? If you check local/session storage, are there any ADAL errors there?

Comment: you have to configure redirectionURL in the adal config, have you done that

Comment: Can you put your adal config here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue we need to set the default page in the application settings. so that after authentication it will be redirected to the page mentioned in the app service and avoids adding null to the base URL. Please refer image [Default page settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwlHt.jpg)